# How to add button into textfield iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, uitextfield

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad{
    UITextField *txt = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 120, 160, 40)];
    txt.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    txt.placeholder = @"enter name";
    [txt setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_chapter.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -16, 0, 0);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    txt.rightView = button;
    txt.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    [self.view addSubview:txt];
}

-(IBAction)refersh:(id)sender{

}
```

above code shows a textfield with button at its right corner but when i clicked on it simulator crash. i can't understand whats the region behind it. any body tell where i'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is spelled -refersh: while you send @selector(refresh:). Is it **the** typo?

Also, you seem to be leaking the UITextField, which is quite easy to fix:

```
[self.view addSubview:[txt autorelease]];
```